# Sencha Js GridPanel rowclick definition issues

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a GridPanel with an rowclick event. According to the documentation from Sencha the event definition should be:

rowclick( this, rowIndex, e )
    this : Grid
    rowIndex : Number
    e : Ext.EventObject

When I do an alert on the rowIndex it comes up as an object[object]. Here is the following code does anyone know what i am doing wrong:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        forceFit: true,
        flex: 2,
        columns: [{header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'}, { header: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age' }],
        store: store,
        listeners :
        {
            'rowclick': function(grid,rowIndex,e)
            {
                //var record = grid.getStore().getAt(0);
                //var someField = record.get('name');
                alert(rowIndex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the second parameter has to be a record, not row index (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-rowclick)

Anyway, here is what you want:

```
listeners: {
            rowclick: function(grid, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ){
                alert(rowIndex);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Aleksei Mialkin much appreciated for the help. I guess I was looking at the wrong class definition or something because the object model I found kept showing me the previous definition. Thanks again.